# Unable to import gardio

Tags: python, gardio

I want to try using gradio, I have installed it to my python library, the installation does not give me any errors. However, when I try to import the library, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)`Input In [5], in <cell line: 1>()----> 1 import gradio as gr
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradio_init_.py:3, in <module>1 import pkgutil----> 3 import gradio.components as components4 import gradio.inputs as inputs5 import gradio.outputs as outputs`
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradio\components.py:32, in <module>30 import PIL.ImageOps31 import requests---> 32 from fastapi import UploadFile33 from ffmpy import FFmpeg34 from gradio_client import media_data
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi_init_.py:7, in <module>3 version = "0.95.2"5 from starlette import status as status----> 7 from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI8 from .background import BackgroundTasks as BackgroundTasks9 from .datastructures import UploadFile as UploadFile
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py:16, in <module>1 from enum import Enum2 from typing import (3     Any,4     Awaitable,(...)13     Union,14 )---> 16 from fastapi import routing17 from fastapi.datastructures import Default, DefaultPlaceholder18 from fastapi.encoders import DictIntStrAny, SetIntStr
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py:24, in <module>22 from fastapi import params23 from fastapi.datastructures import Default, DefaultPlaceholder---> 24 from fastapi.dependencies.models import Dependant25 from fastapi.dependencies.utils import (26     get_body_field,27     get_dependant,(...)30     solve_dependencies,31 )32 from fastapi.encoders import DictIntStrAny, SetIntStr, jsonable_encoder
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\dependencies\models.py:3, in <module>1 from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional, Sequence----> 3 from fastapi.security.base import SecurityBase4 from pydantic.fields import ModelField7 class SecurityRequirement:
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\security_init_.py:1, in <module>----> 1 from .api_key import APIKeyCookie as APIKeyCookie2 from .api_key import APIKeyHeader as APIKeyHeader3 from .api_key import APIKeyQuery as APIKeyQuery
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\security\api_key.py:3, in <module>1 from typing import Optional----> 3 from fastapi.openapi.models import APIKey, APIKeyIn4 from fastapi.security.base import SecurityBase5 from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\openapi\models.py:5, in <module>2 from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Iterable, List, Optional, Union4 from fastapi.logger import logger----> 5 from pydantic import AnyUrl, BaseModel, Field7 try:8     import email_validator  # type: ignore
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic_init_.py:2, in init pydantic.init()
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\dataclasses.py:48, in init pydantic.dataclasses()
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py:120, in init pydantic.main()
TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'`
```

I tried to see if there is a compatibility issue between the Pydantic, FastAPI, and gardio, however that is not clear in the documentation of either. All packages are up to date. I tested importing Pydantic separately and FastAPI separately, I am also getting the same error, I would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Please provide the specific versions of those packages you are using.